# How to remove specific index columns dealing with data visualizatuon power Bi

Tags: powerbi, visualization

How to remove specific columns in power bi

I tried right clicking to delete and then I tried deleting null values row I also tried deleting duplicate values because I couldn't find any assistance in that sense. even through chat gpt

Comment: do you set any relationships for this table with other tables? share your model view or pbix file can help us to understand.